# Can fields validation errors be displayed below the fields?

Tags: webforms

Can field validation errors be displayed below the fields instead of as a list at the top of the form?

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking for something like the [Inline Form Errors](https://www.drupal.org/project/ife) Module. Here is a quote about it (from the module's project page):

> ... allows you to place form submission error inline with the form elements. Three options are provided for setting your inline error behaviour. You can configure the default behaviour or override the behaviour on a per form basis. You can add as many forms as you like.
>
> IFE provides three behaviors for the configured forms
>
> - Leave the messages in place, this option will copy the error messages and place them inline. The original error messages set by Drupal will remain in place
> - Show an alternative message, this option will replace the original messages with a generic error message such as 'Please correct all errors.'. This message can be set in the IFE configuration page. The original error messages are placed inline with the form elements
> - Remove all messages, this option will remove all error messages and place them inline with the form element
>
> In all cases only the messages related to the form will be touched. All other messages will remain in tact.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I may miss something but it seems however that this module does not work for forms made with webform module

Comment: It does, you just need to check the option "Show form_ids on form", visit your form and get its form_id at the bottom and finally add it back to the IFE settings page.

Answer (score 0):

The module of the last answer is only available in alpha for Drupal 7 (but anyway, it's working for me).

But I found this one for Drupal 7, it's just a little bit less good but it does the job if you don't want an alpha version: [Inline Messages](https://www.drupal.org/project/inline_messages). Hope it can help someone on my case.

Here is a quote about it (from the module's project page):

> ...  allows you to move form messages (error/status/warning) from the top of the page to just above where your form appears.
>
> You can enable Inline Messages for your site, content editing or administration pages. Additionally you can also specify forms to include or exclude by id. It will also work for pages with multiple forms.
>
> An example usage is with the comment form, which is typically placed at the bottom of the page. Should an error be generated when someone submits, they jump back to the top of the page. So to get back to the comment form, you have to scroll back to the bottom of the page.
>
> Using jQuery and the jQuery ScrollTo plugin, Inline Messages will capture the $messages, place them just above your form and move the page
> to the top of the form.

Answer (score 0):

The Drupal [Clientside Validation](https://www.drupal.org/project/clientside_validation) module transforms any form to support JavaScript clientside validation and allows the following [error message placements](https://www.drupal.org/node/1324924):

- jQuery selector
- Top of form
- Before label
- After label
- Before input
- After input
- Top of first form
- Custom function

For example, here's a screenshot of a Webform in Drupal 7.x with inline error messages shown below the fields, instead of as a list at the top of the form (which is the default behavior).

---

[image: Screenshot of Drupal Clientside Validation Module]